# Tensorflow linear model returns nan

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very simple model where I try to predict the value for the expression `2x - 2`

It works well, but here is my question.

So far I trained it based on just 20 values (-10 to 10), and it works fine. What I don't understand is that, when I train it on more values, let's say `(-10 to 25)`, my prediction returns `[[nan]]`. Even the model weights are `[<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[nan]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32,  numpy=array([nan], dtype=float32)>]`

Why does adding more training data result in nan?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras


def gen_vals(x):
    return x*2 - 2

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

xs = []
ys = []
for x in range(-10, 10):
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(gen_vals(x))

xs = np.array(xs, dtype=float)
ys = np.array(ys, dtype=float)

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=500)

print(model.predict([20]))
```

Comment: What is the accuracy when trained on larger range?

Comment: To begin with, is this a classification problem or a regression problem? Why do you use accuracy?

Comment: Regression problem with the aim of predicting the y value, and also please ignore the accuracy metric. Even without it I get nan

Answer (score 1):

So I checked your code and the problem is in your loss function. You are using `mean_squared_erro`. Due to this, your error is reaching infinity.

```
Epoch 1/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 22108.5449 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 2046332.6250 - accuracy: 0.0286
Epoch 3/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 18862860288.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 8550264864768.0000 - accuracy: 0.0286
Epoch 5/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 24012283831123968.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 22680820415763316736.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1655609635839244500992.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 611697420191128514199552.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 229219278753403035799519232.0000 - accuracy: 0.0286
Epoch 10/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 2146224141449145393293494845440.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1169213631609383639522618269237248.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1042864695227246165669313090114551808.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: inf - accuracy: 0.0286                                        
Epoch 14/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: inf - accuracy: 0.0286
Epoch 15/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: inf - accuracy: 0.0286
```

As MSE loss function squares the actual loss and due to the toy dataset that you have it might happen that it reaches `inf` as in your case.

I will suggest using `MAE` mean absolute error for your toy example and toy network.
I checked the network provides decent results.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras


def gen_vals(x):
    return x*2 - 2

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mae', metrics=['accuracy'])

xs = []
ys = []
for x in range(-10, 25):
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(gen_vals(x))

Epoch 1/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 14.5341 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 7.5144 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.4349 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.3424 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.5290 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.4349 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2839 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.4003 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.4593 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.4561 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.4761 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3080 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.1885 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/15
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2665 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
[[38.037006]]
```